# NVidia GTX 970 with triple 3k monitors?

Tags: multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

I've got:

- NVidia GTX 970
- LG Ultrawide 34" 3k Monitor.

And I'm looking to buy:

- 2x Dell Ultrasharp 34" 4k Monitors. (running at 3k though, not 4k)

Is the GTX 970 good enough for this setup?

As a side note if relevant I'm running an i7-6700k, 32GB RAM and 750W PSU.

Comment: For normal application use, it shouldn't be an issue as far as I can see.

Comment: @mt025 What about for gaming?